# issue after zooming i want full image not only zoom part of image

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, uiimageview

[image: this is my image without zoom]
[image: And i am getting like this i want full image not only zoomable part]

Am dropping a pin on `UIImageView` for that first i am taking one `UIView`. Inside `UIView` i have `UIScrollview` for zooming functionality and then inside `UIScrollview` i have `UIImageView` for me zoooming functionality works properly.

```
UIView 
    UIScrollView
         UIImageView
```

But after zoom image i want full image not only zoom part of image and i am taking `UIView` for combine pin image and main image both in one image.

I have tried some code let me show you

As you can see my code i am fetching frame of main `UIView` which is converted as image than i am passing that frame to another `ViewController` and then i am setting it to `UIView` but it can't set i check i am getting frame perfect as expected but still i am getting only zoom part of image.

As i mentioned my code below, am not clear to understand why am unable to set frame so please someone help me

```
@IBAction func btnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let VC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ThirdViewController") as! ThirdViewController
        let image = conImgView.getImage()
        VC.image = image
        if let frame = conImgView.superview?.convert(conImgView.frame, to: nil) {
            print(frame)
            VC.frame1 = frame
        }
        self.present(VC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

I want full image after zooming not only part which is zoomed in sort i want full image when i am redirection to another ViewController on button click.

Comment: Please some one give ma suggestion

Comment: You can take screenshot as soon as user come to first screen, and pass that screenshot image to next view.

Comment: Yes first image is normal without zoom when i zoom then got to next VC with image i am getting zoomed image i want full image without zoom

Comment: try my solution and update me it's working or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set your image to display fully means set `contentMode` as `scaleAspectFit`.

```
let yourImageView : UIImageView = UIImageView()
yourImageView.frame = customFrame
yourImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

Comment: Not working still i am getting only zoom part on image

Comment: Replace following line let image = conImgView.getImage()  into conImgView.image

Comment: no because get image is my function from which i  convert UIView to Uiimage conImgView is my UIVIew